# How to create a dictionary in C?

Tags: c, dictionary

I'm programming a microcontroller in C and as part of it want to display certain letters on a 7 segment display. Each letter has a corresponding number that makes the 7 segment display show the letter. There's no real pattern to it cause the number is just made by adding up the bits on the 7 segment display that are needed to show the letter so it'd be really nice if I could create some sort of dictionary to do this.

If I was using C# or something I'd just make a dictionary and then add the letters as keys and the numbers as values but as far as I know I can't do this in C. Is there another way to do it or do should I just write a function like `int displayletter(char letter)` that uses a bunch of if statements to return the right numbers?

Comment: Look for a trie implementation in C, failing that, a hashtable could also work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create an array

```
 int values[26];
```

and populate it with the values for each letter, however they're calculated

Then create a function that takes a character and returns an int

```
int GetValueFromChar(char c)
{
    return values[c - 'A'];
}
```

This is simplistic, as it assumes you'll only use upper case letters in an ASCII character set, but you should get the idea.

Comment: What if the computer is using the EBCDIC character set and not ASCII?

Comment: Unless you're IBM in 1975, it's not going to be EBCDIC.

Comment: @Swiss: that's a good point. I am assuming an ASCII character set, but the underlying mechanism should be the same. I've updated the answer to reflect that assumption.

Comment: @Matt Ellen: Characters in EBCDIC aren't continuous - they're broken into chunks. You might want to use 'A' instead of 65 to make this a little more portable and readable though.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: From what I've heard, z/OS still uses EBCDIC as its primary character set.

Comment: EBCDIC is still _heavily_ used. Just the one (System z) platform but it's _everywhere_.

Comment: Thanks, great idea. Totally forgot that ASCII characters are just considered to be numbers but that should work great. :)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to just use a function and a switch statement... I believe for this purpose the switch statement would be very efficient.  I also second the Judy library as a good one to use for efficient mapping, but it's kind of overkill for this.